# Relatively included script, but it shows Not Found error

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

I have a `smarty-test01` smarty project.

In my `templates/index2.tpl`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>dialog</title>
    <!--jquery-->
    <script src="http://libs.baidu.com/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../libs/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script> // you see there I import the jquery-ui.
    <!--Css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../libs/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/css/base/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    ...
```

I imported the jquery-ui and jquery-ui-css.

but when I access the `http://localhost:63342/smarty-test01/index2.php`, the browser says Not found the jquery-ui and its stylesheet. I am sure the relative path is correct.

[image]

---

The directories tree:

```
.
├── CONSTANTS.php
├── cache
├── configs
│   └── constants.php
├── htdocs
│   ├── index.php
│   └── index2.php
├── index.php
├── index2.php
├── libs
│   └── jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom
│       ├── css
│       │   └── base
...
│       │   └── ui.widget.jquery.json
│       ├── index.html
│       └── js
│           ├── jquery-1.8.3.js
│           ├── jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js
│           └── jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js
├── smarty.php
├── templates
│   ├── index.tpl
│   └── index2.tpl
└── templates_c
    ├── 8b747b0f978b4e5206c429d91816c400edfe7ec5_0.file.index2.tpl.php
    ├── 976090f2d104294efca669338810dea6bf8e1484_2.file.debug.tpl.php
    └── aac75150379166297487ae8ee5a1de73ee3e89c7_0.file.index.tpl.php
```

---

**EDIT-1**

Because in the phpStorm, the editor do not shows that's a wrong path, so this is strange. I also tried the absolute path.

Comment: Well, you have the expansion to the absolute path there. Is it correct?

Comment: I tried, not work.

Comment: That's `index2.php` though

Comment: ignore this, its index2.php. for the post, I say index.php

Comment: Then the relative path is wrong. It would help if you showed us the relevant part of directory structure for your project.

Comment: Ok, just making sure you didn't accidentally edit `index.php` and calling `index2.php`. Does the file `/libs/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js` exist in your document root? Any `.htaccess` rules that prohibit loading of .js/.css files?

Comment: first get the full location and then compare your php location and then use it.

Comment: Are you using `/htdocs/index2.php` or `/index2.php`?

Comment: @kerbholz No, I use `http://localhost:63342/smarty-test01/index2.php`

Comment: just remove `../` The path should be relative to the php file, not the template.

Comment: Confused, there is no `smarty-test01` folder in that directory structure.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I tried the absolute path.

Comment: I did not say "absolute path". I said "remove `../`". That would be `src="libs/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"` which is still a relative path, but relative to the php file. Or substitute `../` with `./` if you prefer.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Oh, yeah, this works. although in editor it says not exists. but why? because I use absolute path do not work.

Comment: I think your editor doesn't know what a template file is and how it interacts with your application.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any default CSS file in the directory? If so, then remove or rename it and see if you get the expected result.

Or alternatively you can try this:

```
/../libs/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/css/base/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css"
```